# Why should momentum be conserved in special relativity?

Tags: special-relativity, momentum, conservation-laws, inertial-frames

This is more of a philosophical question than an actual physics question, but I don't see a clear reason why relativistic momentum, or energy for that matter, should be conserved.

The equivalence principle, simply stated, states that the laws of physics are the same in all inertial frames. But what makes a given statement a law of physics?

Why couldn't we simply say that momentum is conserved only for $v\ll c$ ? Is such conservation a result of special relativity or a requirement that we add and use to define momentum in the relativistic setting?

How do we judge whether or not any given statement is a universal law of physics?

Comment: It's an interesting question, for help answerng it could you tell me what you accept as a proof that momentum is conserved in newtonian physics?  After all the reasons are similar.

Comment: @shaihorowitz given the definition of force as the time rate of change of momentum, if the net force on an object is zero then the time derivative of linear momentum is zero, meaning it is conserved. And it's conserved under galilean transformations, given that it differs by an additive constant. That's my reasoning for that in the case of newtonian mechanics.

Comment: That the laws of physics are the same in all inertial reference frame is one of the postulates of special relativity. The [equivalence principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_principle) is something else.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_theories_modified_by_general_relativity#Conservation_of_energy%E2%80%93momentum "Unlike classical mechanics and special relativity, it is not usually possible to unambiguously define the total energy and momentum in general relativity, so the tensorial conservation laws are local statements only (see ADM energy, though)." We can't in general say that momentum is globally conserved in GR - we can't in general express momentum globally in GR.

Answer (score 25):

The conservation of momentum can be derived from the invariance of the Lagrangian under spatial translations. This follows from Noether’s theorem, so it applies for special relativity. Furthermore you can use Noether’s theorem to derive the form of relativistic momentum.

Regarding determining if something is a law of physics: that can only be done experimentally. You have to show that a candidate law of physics matches the results of experiments. The postulate of relativity is that such laws will not depend on the reference frame, but that claim can only be validated experimentally.

Comment: I checked the answer, but would like to point out that the laws of physics were first discovered from **observations on data and experiments**, that is why they were called laws, and then a mathematical model, the theory, was chosen so that the laws were manifest in its calculations.

Comment: @annav It depends on the example. The laws of black hole thermodynamics, while indirectly testable with acoustic black hole experiments, were deduced before any empirical confirmation. Or to take a less controversial example, I doubt FGR was gleaned from experiments before theory.

Comment: @J.G. what is FGR , fermi's golden rule?  I am talking about basic laws used as axioms in phyics theories. If there were no conservation of energy momentum angular momentum there would be different physics theories to fit and predict data.

Comment: @annav sure, the experiments can be done before or after formulating the law. But the point remains that only experiments can show that a statement is indeed a law of physics.

Comment: But the thing is, we have a quantity in newtonian mechanics which we "call" momentum, which is the mass times the velocity. But it seems to me that in special relativity we assume the conservation of momentum first to then define a new quantity that is conserved and then "call" that new quantity the relativistic momentum. And it's not obvious to me why we do that. It kind of assumes the conservation of a quantity before defining the quantity itself. Why not take the quantity of mass times velocity and call it momentum and just say it's not conserved in all settings?

Comment: I get that there's utility in that and that the new momentum encapsulates the old momentum in the low velocity limit, but is there even a unique way to derive such a thing? Is there a unique quantity that encapsulates the low velocity limit and fits observational data and is conserved?

Comment: @user626542 I thought that I explained that already, perhaps it was not as clear as I thought. We use Noether's theorem to derive the conserved quantity corresponding to the spatial translation symmetry of the Lagrangian. We call that quantity "momentum", regardless of whether we are using a relativistic or non-relativistic Lagrangian.

Comment: @user626542 It is also the case in Newtonian mechanics that we identify a quantity to call momentum precisely because it is conserved. The quantity $mv$ isn't hugely natural, interesting, or significant independently of its being conserved in some class of scenarios. We observe this quantity is conserved (either experimentally or within the context of a model), and then we give it a name because that's useful. The same is true of energy.

Answer (score 11):

Dale's answer describes nicely where momentum conservation comes from, but I thought it might be useful to emphasize that momentum *need not* be conserved in a relativistic model, just as it need not be conserved in a non-relativistic model. There's nothing about special (or indeed, general) relativity which requires spatial translation symmetry, and so the Noether current corresponding to that symmetry will generically not be conserved.

As far as we know, when all interactions are taken into account then momentum *is* a conserved quantity; nevertheless, that is not required by the postulates of special or general relativity, and it does not preclude the use of effective models in which momentum is not conserved (e.g. a particle moving through a background Schwarzschild spacetime in GR).

Comment: While studying SR, homogeneity and isotropy popped up as basic assumptions underlying the theory. So does it mean that it's because of these two that we get translation symmetry, and because of translation symmetry we get conservation of momentum? I've heard (in Veritasium's video on one-way speed of light) that there are some formulations of SR that don't assume isotropy (i.e. speed of light is different in different directions). In such formulations, would I be correct in saying that momentum isn't necessarily conserved because we no longer have translation symmetry?

Answer (score 6):

The short answer? Because the Lorentz group is a subgroup of the Poincaré group. The latter includes *translations*.

Answer (score 0):

"Physics is the same in all inertial frames."

This is a law of physics because it is what we see when we look at the world we live in.

The basis of any theory of physics is looking at the world around us, and then try to find basic principles that fit with what we see.

Starting with this principle and other basic assumptions, one can prove that energy and momentum are conserved.